# Recursively Counting Files in Folders and Subfolders Including Root VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, file, recursion, count, directory

I am trying to count the total number of files in folders and subfolders in CDROM drive F:\ The total number of files on the CDROM is 58 but the total file count returned by my code below is 39. All 39 files counted are contained in folders and the missing 19 files are in the root of drive F:\

How can I count the files in the root as well as the folders \ subfolders?

I am using a recursive search as I found it works better with Try\Catch exception errors than IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(DirectoryPath, "*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count etc.

Regards

Georgy

```
Public Sub Search1()

    Dim DirectoryPath = TextBox1.Text
    Dim TotalFileCount As Long = 0

    Search2(DirectoryPath, TotalFileCount)
    MsgBox(TotalFileCount)

End Sub

Public Sub Search2(ByVal DirectoryPath As String, ByRef TotalFileCount As Integer)

    Dim FileName As String = Nothing

    Try
        For Each Directory In IO.Directory.GetDirectories(DirectoryPath)
            For Each File In IO.Directory.GetFiles(Directory, "*")
                FileName = New IO.FileInfo(File).FullName
                TotalFileCount += 1
            Next
            Search2(Directory, TotalFileCount)
        Next
    Catch ua As UnauthorizedAccessException
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Exception: " & ua.Message & " " & FileName)
    Catch ex As Exception
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Exception: " & ex.Message & " " & FileName)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: @varocabas -  TotalFileCount is being passed ByRef.  The answer you downvoted should fix the OP's issue.

Comment: @varocabas It compiles if Infer is on.

Comment: @varocarbas - Let me apologize for all of us, including me, that make sloppy copy / paste mistakes when posting.  There has been so much editing and deleting that, in this case, I am not certain what particularly I am apologizing for, but I do apologize.  Personally, after 45 years of programming, I am still looking for perfection.

Answer (score 2):

In your Search2 method you should find files outside the foreach loop of directories. Your method is looking for subfolders and files inside these folders but not files inside the current folder.

Try this

```
Public Sub Search2(ByVal DirectoryPath As String, ByRef TotalFileCount As Integer)
    Dim FileName As String = Nothing
    Try
        For Each Directory In IO.Directory.GetDirectories(DirectoryPath)
            Search2(Directory, TotalFileCount)
        Next
        For Each File In IO.Directory.GetFiles(DirectoryPath, "*")
            FileName = New IO.FileInfo(File).FullName
            TotalFileCount += 1
        Next
    Catch ua As UnauthorizedAccessException
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Exception: " & ua.Message & " " & FileName)
    Catch ex As Exception
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Exception: " & ex.Message & " " & FileName)
    End Try
End Sub
```

In addition It would be easy to understand, I think, if you just return the number of files (use function instead of sub and a ByRef parameter) and sum this value to get the total number.

Comment: Please, correct your code. Right now it doesn't even compile.

Comment: @varocabas It compiles if Infer is on.  Please stop deleting comments.

Comment: @dbasnett (congratulations for having spotted a mistake I did; but don't start thinking that this is usual). Firstly this is not an acceptable condition (= the OP should have highlighted this issue). Secondly: are you saying that writing "End If" rather than "End Sub" can be corrected via Infer On?! LOL.

Comment: We are two seperate people and we do not know each other in any way. However I believe it is not a constructive discussion happening here. I was not able to see all the comments written before, so it would be wrong for me to make any comments about it. Please feel free to edit or point out about mistakes/enhancements on my answer.

Comment: @varocarbas - This answer compiles with Infer On (might need Strict Off), but it basically showed the OP their mistake and answered why the counts were wrong.

Comment: @varocarbas - There were a lot of edits and a lot of deletion in this thread.  When I saw it I don't know what version I was looking at, but I think the if had been changed to sub by then.  The absence of 'As' is obvious, hence the comment about Infer.  The guts of this answer pointed out the flaw from the OP, and I do agree about the placement of the Try- catch blocks.  I only get on here a few hours before going to work or I would've posted my own answer.  Once again the clock says off to work.  Please do not question my honesty ever.

Comment: @varocarbas - Per one of your deleted comments I read your profile.

Comment: @dbasnett (not sure if there is a new misunderstanding; so here it goes a new clarification) Yesterday, I wrote a last comment to you saying something like "Your last comment proved me that this is a waste of time. SO is very big, please don't talk to me again. Now I will delete my comments because they are offtopic; you are free to do the same thing or keep all of them here". I will let this comment for a long enough while. Afterwards I will delete it. PS: my profile includes clarifications addressed to people who get easily confused (I don't want them to waste my time).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method to try

```
Public Function FileCount(DirPath As String, Optional IncludeSubDirs As Boolean = True) As Long
    Dim rv As Long = 0L
    Try
        If IncludeSubDirs Then
            For Each dirname As String In IO.Directory.GetDirectories(DirPath)
                rv += FileCount(dirname, IncludeSubDirs)
            Next
            rv += IO.Directory.GetFiles(DirPath).Length
        End If
    Catch ua As UnauthorizedAccessException
        'Stop
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Stop
    End Try
    Return rv
End Function
```

Tested with

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim DirectoryPath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)
    Dim stpw As Stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew

    Dim TotalFileCount As Long = FileCount(DirectoryPath)

    stpw.Stop()
    Dim rslts As String = String.Format("Total Files = {0:n0}.  Took {1:n0} ms.", TotalFileCount, stpw.ElapsedMilliseconds)
    Debug.WriteLine(rslts)
End Sub
```